# How determine Array length

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm trying to create a function which determines length of Array. My code doesn't work, please HELP!

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

  int ArrayLength(int Array[])
    {
        int i = 0;
        while (Array[i] != NULL)
        {
            i++;
        }
        return i;
    }

int main(void)
{
    int test[5] = { 4,5,6,7,1 };
    int testLen = ArrayLength(test);
    cout << " test length  = " << testLen;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's not how arrays work. There's no guarantee that the element next to the last one is NULL, quite the contrary, it could be anything.

Comment: When reading past the array length, the value isn't `0`, but undefined behavior. It may have any value or crash the program.

Answer (score 2):

An array is not NULL terminated, so you cannot assume that there is an end element equal to NULL. When an array is passed to your function `ArrayLength()`, it's decayed to a pointer to the first array element with all information about the size of the array lost.

In order to get the size of an array (not a pointer pointing to its first element) in bytes, use the `sizeof()` operator.

```
int array[5] = {0,1,2,3,4};
static_assert(sizeof(array) == 5*sizeof(int),"!!");
```

If you want a function to take `array` as argument and return its size, you can construct a template:

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
size_t ArrayLength(const T& [N])
{ return N; }
```

Answer (score 2):

When an array is passed by value it is implicitly converted to pointer to its first element. Moreover arrays do not have a sentinel value.

The function can be declared like

```
template <size_t N>
constexpr size_t ArrayLength(const int(&a)[N])
{
    return N;
}
```

Or like

```
template <class T, size_t N>
constexpr size_t ArrayLength(const T(&a)[N])
{
    return N;
}
```

Take into account that there is standard C++ class `std::extent` declared in header `<type_traits>` that does the task.

For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

int main()
{
    int test[5] = { 4,5,6,7,1 };

    std::cout << std::extent<decltype(test)>() << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find length of array using this

```
int testLen = (sizeof(test)/sizeof(*test));
```

Hope this helps !